# TFS task Windows Machine File Copy -> Advance-> Clean Target is not happening

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, copy-paste

In Release Definition I have added Task "Windows Machine File Copy" and in the task configuration I have selected Advance option for "clean Target".

But destination folder cleaning is not ḥappening as before copying files from the source machine to the destination machine's folder.

**Server Details-**

TFS Version 16.131.28106.2

Source machine and Destination machine - Windows server 2012 R2

**Task Config-**
[image]

Please Suggest what I am missing...

Comment: Does your agent has enough permission to delete files in the target location?

Comment: Yes. The user is having admin access to that build machine. If there is any new file or change in a file this is coming while copying.